# Why can .NET not have memory leaks?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

Ignoring unsafe code, .NET cannot have memory leaks. I've read this endlessly from many experts and I believe it. However, I do not understand why this is so.

It is my understanding that the framework itself is written in C++ and C++ is susceptible to memory leaks.

- Is the underlying framework so well-written, that it absolutely does not have any possibility of internal memory leaks?
- Is there something within the framework's code that self-manages and even cures its own would-be memory leaks?
- Is the answer something else that I haven't considered?

Comment: Please post a link to any "experts" saying that it is impossible for .NET frameworks (or *any* framework in *any* language) to have memory leaks. I need to write that person an e-mail.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: see answers below. It's not that the .NET Framework is flawless or can't leak. The answer to the question relies on the distinction between the classic memory allocation/deallocation done *within* the framework's source code vs. the memory management done *by* the framework with regard to handing references. This is probably too simplistic of a summary, but there are many wonderful and more complete explanations below.

Comment: I'm merely reading your question as it is currently stated: "Ignoring unsafe code, .NET cannot have memory leaks. I've read this endlessly from many experts and I believe it." Frameworks have bugs that get fixed, which is why the get updated. Again, I'll say that I'm interested in reading some of these "expert" opinions, so please post links to such.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are already some good answers here, but I want to address one additional point.  Let's look very carefully again at your specific question:

---

It is my understanding that the framework itself is written in C++ and C++ is susceptible to memory leaks.

- Is the underlying framework so well-written, that it absolutely does not have any possibility of internal memory leaks?
- Is there something within the framework's code that self-manages and even cures its own would-be memory leaks?
- Is the answer something else that I haven't considered?

---

The key here is to distinguish between *your* code and *their* code.  The .Net framework (and Java, Go, python, and other garbage-collected languages) promise that if you rely on *their* code, *your* code will not leak memory... at least in the traditional sense.  You might find yourself in situations where some objects are not freed as you expect, but these cases are subtly different from traditional memory leaks because the objects are still reachable in your program.

You are confused because you correctly understand that this is not the same thing as saying any program you create can't possibly have a traditional memory leak at all.  There could still be a bug in *their* code that leaks memory.

So now you have to ask yourself: would you rather trust your code, or their code?  Keep in mind here that their code is not only tested by the original developers (just like yours, right?), it's also battle-hardened from daily use by thousands (perhaps millions) of other programmers like yourself.  Any significant memory leak issues would be among the first things identified and corrected.  Again, I'm not saying it's not possible.  It's just that it's generally a better idea to trust their code than it is your own... at least in this respect.

Therefore the correct answer here is that it's a variant of your first suggestion:

> Is the underlying framework so well-written, that it absolutely does not have any possibility of internal memory leaks?

It's not that there's no possibility, but that it's much safer than managing it yourself. I'm certainly not aware of any *known* leaks in the framework.

Comment: Eric Lippert should read this whole question (hoping for a vanity search win here).

Comment: Just to add to that: *their* code indeed has memory leaks (WPF has quite a few leaks, one example: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529736/wpf-progressbar-isindeterminate-true-causes-unmanaged-memory-leak). Not trying to bash (I like .net :)), just to give an example.

Comment: @Michael:  Well there is _their_ code and then there is _their_ code.  That is there is stuff like the WPF ProgressBar and there is stuff like the `String` type.    The WPF ProgressBar has as much chance of containing the odd bug or two as _our_ code, however the base .NET code on which we all rely ( _them_ and _us_ ) is much less likely to have such bugs.

Comment: Thank you. You cleared up my confusion by making the distinction of my code vs. their code. If, when I run my managed code, there is evidence of a memory and I find that the leak is occurring in a faulty part of the Framework, then my code is still not considered to be leaking. It is the Framework that is leaking. If my code were to run on a non-faulty version of the Framework, there would be no leak. Therefore, even with a memory leak present, my managed code still does not contain a memory leak. That was the contradiction I couldn't reconcile before.

Answer (score 94):

.NET *can* have memory leaks.

Mostly, people refer to the Garbage Collector, which decides when an object (or whole object cycle) can be gotten rid of. This avoids the *classic* c and c++ style memory leaks, by which I mean allocating memory and not freeing it later on.

However, many times programmers do not realize that objects still have dangling references and do not get garbage collected, causing a... memory leak.

This is normally the case when events are registered (with `+=`) but not unregistered later on, but also when accessing unmanaged code (using pInvokes or objects that use underlying system resources, such as the filesystem or database connections) and not disposing properly of the resources.

Comment: For example: Forgetting to dispose of an OS widget.

Comment: GC is much more complicated than just reference counting, but other than that yes.  The memory leak in C/C++ is "something that is not freed but no longer referenced".  Memory leak in Java/.NET is "something that we are still referencing but shouldn't be".  Of course the .NET type of leaks can still happen in C/C++, so there is somewhat less chances to have a memory leak in .NET, but still very much a possibility.

Comment: Reference counting is rarely used in high performance virtual machines. The overhead is enormous and killing for multithreaded applications.

Answer (score 15):

After reviewing Microsoft documentation, specifically "[Identifying Memory Leaks in the CLR](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318263)", Microsoft does make the statement that as long as you are not implementing unsafe code within your application that it is not possible to have a memory leak

Now, they also point out the concept of a perceived memory leak, or as was pointed out in the comments a "resource leak", which is the use of an object that has lingering references and is not disposed of properly.  This can happen with IO Objects, DataSets, GUI elements, and the like.  They are what I would typically equate to a "memory leak" when working with .NET, but they are not leaks in the traditional sense.

Comment: Certain .NET classes, such as the ones you mentioned, wrap Windows kernel objects (such as file handles), so letting them drop out of scope without calling `Dispose` delays the release of the underlying resource until GC eventually gets around to it.  This sort of error can leave files locked and inaccessible, so it's really bad, but it's not a genuine memory leak.

Comment: @Steven Yes to a certain point...but in reality it is a leak, as how do you fix it.  I guess it depends on your definition of a "leak"

Comment: Maybe I'm being picky, but my notion of a leak is that a resource is lost *permanently* (or at least until the process shuts down).  The event error is a genuine leak, while this example is just an undesirable slowness. Again, it may be a fine point, and I'd certainly fix such a problem immediately.

Comment: @Steven - depending on usage, it could be lost until the process shuts down, I see this all the time with Files, XMLSerializers, and other objects in code.

Comment: Handles are *resources*, and failing to release (dispose) them leads to *resource* leaks, but that is not commonly called a *memory* leak.

Comment: @Aaron: Handles have memory associated with them, as well, although it's in some table the OS manages.  However, this is not a real leak, as the handle *will* get closed as soon as the GC gets around to it, just as a string you build only gets freed when the GC sweeps up, not immediately.  Delaying is not leaking.

Comment: @Mitch: It's certainly possible that the handle won't get closed until the AppDomain shuts down because there's insufficient memory pressure to cause a cleanup in time.  Then again, that's true for strings, too, and we don't consider that a leak.

Comment: @Steven/@Aaron - I've updated my post to talk about this a bit more, and reference the Microsoft documentation on the subject...

Comment: @Mitch: I'm happy with those changes.

Comment: @Steven - I figured you would be.  In reality it is a "memory" issue, but to be technical and literal, it isn't a memory leak, so I see your point as well.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Even though there is a theoretical difference between leaking a resource and simply delaying its cleanup, in practice, failure to clean up unmanaged resources often leads to pile-ups and starvation of system resources because the GC frees the memory (and runs the finalizers) much slower than the resources really need to be cleaned up.  Also, unmanaged wrappers don't *have* to implement finalizers, even though it's poor practice not to.

Comment: @Mitchel: While this may not be the appropriate forum to discuss it, I would say that resource leaks are *worse* than memory leaks; memory leaks may take hours or days before making any significant impact on the machine, but files and sockets left open can cause immediate and serious problems; depending on the kind of resource, even termination of the process may not force a cleanup (this includes certain GDI handles, mutexes, etc.)  I don't mean to sound preachy but I do think it's important for developers to understand the difference between memory management and OS resource management.

Comment: @Aaron: I've said all along that we should clean up both actual memory leaks and the other, similar problems, such as delayed resource release.  In fact, I even agree that a memory leak is often less of a problem than, say, holding a file handle open for a few minutes and making everything fail.  I think there is a distinction here that makes a difference, though, so I'm glad that Mitch's current version clarified this so well.

Comment: @Aaron - I couldn't agree more...just ask the people that work with me....I have a regular soapbox talk at least once a week :)  I'm starting to feel a blog posting coming on though....

Answer (score 12):

Due to garbage collection, you can't have regular memory leaks (aside from special cases such as unsafe code and P/Invoke).  However, you can certainly unintentionally keep a reference alive forever, which *effectively* leaks memory.

*edit*

The best example I've seen so far of a genuine leak is the event handler += mistake.

*edit*

See below for an explanation of the mistake, and of the conditions under which it qualifies as a genuine leak as opposed to an almost-genuine leak.

Comment: Could you explain "the event handler += mistake"? Excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: @Pwninstein. If you attacht an event handler with MyClass.CoolEvent += new EventHandler(HandleCoolEvent);
This essentially adds an eventhandler to an internal list. And if you want to avoid memory leaks, you should detach in the same way but replace += with -=. This removes the event handler from the internal list.

Comment: To add to that, if you don't remove the event (or the object itself, or both, i don't recall at the moment) will live forever, or at least till the end of your program.

Comment: I'd say it's only a "true" leak if you don't have delegate anymore, so you can't `-=` it even if you want.  This can happen immediately if you use an anonymous method, or later if you lose all references to the class instance (but it's still stuck in memory, of course).

Comment: I would say that based on the definition of a "true leak" that is popular in this thread, the += doesn't qualify. That is because the class that holds the event can, at any time, say `MyEvent = null` thus removing the reference and allowing the GC to free the memory. That is to say, the reference itself *is* still available, though only to that one class.

Comment: @Jeff: That's a very interesting point.  As you say, the reference is in that multi-delegate somewhere, even if you can't reach it, and you can dump the reference by killing the entire delegate.  However, I was working under the assumption that if you're hooking onto an event, you don't necessarily have access to the source code of what you're hooking onto, so there might not be any way to kill the delegate.  So, depending on the details, you may well be correct.  Regardless, even when it doesn't *quite* qualify as a proper leak, it's very, very close.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in why this was downvoted.  Do you think I'm being too picky about what constitutes a proper leak?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a memory leak in .NET, which doesn't involve unsafe/pinvoke and doesn't even involve event handlers.

Suppose you're writing a background service that receives a series of messages over a network and processes them. So you create a class to hold them.

```
class Message 
{
  public Message(int id, string text) { MessageId = id; Text = text; }
  public int MessageId { get; private set; }
  public string Text { get; private set; }
}
```

OK, so far so good. Later on you realize that some requirement in the system could sure be made easier if you had a reference to the previous message available when you do the processing. There could be any number of reasons for wanting this.

So you add a new property...

```
class Message
{
  ...
  public Message PreviousMessage { get; private set; }
  ...
}
```

And you write the code to set it. And, of course, somewhere in the main loop you have to have a variable to keep up with the last message:

```
  Message lastMessageReceived;
```

Then you discover some days later than your service has bombed, because it has filled up all the available memory with a long chain of obsolete messages.

Comment: This isn't so much a leak as bad design.  It's doing exactly what was asked: keeping all previous messages in memory.  There's no way it could know which messages are ok to drop.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - When does the computer ever not do exactly what it was asked? Memory leaks are caused by bad design or buggy implementation. You could call this hypothetical situation a bug or a bad design, but, either way, the intent wasn't to fill up the memory with useless objects.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm being picky.  I would consider it a leak only if it wasn't completely obvious that it will increase memory usage indefinitely.  The code you showed has the same symptom as a bad leak -- memory usage grows until a crash -- but it's got a different cause.  Forgetting to unlink an event handler, however, is subtle.

Comment: Let me clarify what I said.  In C, if you malloc a buffer and lose all references to it, that's a leak because there's nothing your code can do at this point to recover that lost memory.  In the sample above, the code can just "leak" the top reference to the chain and GC will deallocate all of it.  It is the possibility of clean-up that prevents me from accepting something as a genuine leak.

Comment: It is a leak, but it's not a _traditional_ leak.  .Net precludes traditional leaks, but there are still many way to create a non-traditional leak.

Comment: @Joel: Agreed.  Maybe we need to redefine a leak more broadly as any circumstance where you might reasonably believe that a resource was freed, but it is not released in a timely manner.

Comment: I'm not sure that this qualifies as a real memory leak. This is all good usable information. I can use myMessage.PreviousMessage.PreviousMessage.PreviousMessage etc. and get lots of information. None of this is really lost in the ether as happens in traditional memory leaks. If we're just talking about unintended memory "leaks" of this kind, you need only discuss statics and singletons to get an infinite number of real world examples.

Comment: Is the downvote based on the usefulness of the information, or is it a proxy vote to say "This doesn't fit my personal definition of 'memory leak'"?

Comment: @Dinah - Statics and singletons using up an unintended amount of memory?

Comment: +1 for the clarifications in comments, which make this entry valuable.

Comment: @Jeffrey: RE statics and singletons: I've seen lots of code (especially on CodeProject) where a static or singleton is used to hold a reference when the object doesn't really need to persist. The reference doesn't get lost or become inaccessible, it's just that the coder forgot that it's there. However, since the object is active in a static, it's not getting collected. This is the same as what you described and I do not consider it to be a memory leak because it's usable, active, and could still be deallocated. In C/C++, when it leaks you can't use or deallocate. It's just hogging memory.

Comment: @Dinah - Perhaps my useage is idiosyncratic, but I have always understood "leak" to be an active thing, as opposed to "bloat" which is static. Thus, a leaky program is one that consumes more and more memory over time (in a way that isn't expected by the requirements of the application), so that if it's left to run long enough it will consume all the memory available. A bloated program is one that takes more memory than it really should (based on the requirements of the application). If others precieve the terms differntly than I do, then I shall change my useage.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I agree with Steven Sudit both in his definition and in that the conversation in the comments clears up confusion and makes the answer more valuable. However, SO won't allow me to change my downvote to up until the answer is edited. It says it's too old. If you will make an edit, I'll go back and change the vote.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I hope you don't mind, I made a trivial edit in your post for the purposes of being able to reverse my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Here are other memory leaks that this guy found using ANTS .NET Profiler: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/tracing-memory-leaks-in-.net-applications-with-ants-profiler/

Comment: Interesting link.  ANTS helped me confirm that SMO was leaking, so I'd likewise recommend it.

Comment: +1 At my last job we used this profiler to find a memory leak in a 3rd party dll we were using. In that case, it happened to be a leak in the dll's unsafe code and not managed code, but it was still quite useful in helping us find the leak we'd suspected.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is possible to write software, e.g. the .NET runtime environment (the CLR), that does not leak memory if one is careful enough. But since Microsoft does issue updates to the .NET framework via Windows Update from time to time, I'm fairly sure that there *are* occasional bugs even in the CLR.

All software can leak memory.

But as others have already pointed out, there are other kinds of memory leaks. While the garbage collector takes care of "classic" memory leaks, there's still, for example, the problem of freeing so-called **unmanaged resources** (such as database connections, open files, GUI elements, etc.). That's where the `IDisposable` interface comes in.

Also, I've recently come across with a possible leaking of memory in a **.NET-COM interop** setting. COM components use reference counts to decide when they can be freed. .NET adds yet another reference counting mechanism to this which can be influenced via the static `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class.

After all, you still need to be careful about resource management, even in a .NET program.

Comment: Objects that implement IDisposable almost always implement finalizers, so the underlying resource is eventually cleaned up by the GC, though not necessarily in a timely manner.

Comment: Not always.  Some root themselves, and will not be cleaned up until the AppDomain is shut down.

Comment: @kyor: That's interesting.  Could you point me to an example of a self-rooting object of the sort you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely have memory leaks in .NET code.  Some objects will, in some cases, root themselves (though these are typically `IDisposable`).  Failing to call `Dispose()` on an object in this case will absolutely cause a real, C/C++ style memory leak with an allocated object that you have no way to reference.

In some cases, certain timer classes can have this behavior, as one example.

Any case where you have an asynchronous operation that may reschedule itself, you have a potential leak.  The async op will typically root the callback object, preventing a collection.  During execution, the object is rooted by the executing thread, and then the newly-scheduled operation re-roots the object.

Here's some sample code using `System.Threading.Timer`.

```
public class Test
{
    static public int Main(string[] args)
    {
        MakeFoo();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.Collect();
        System.Console.ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }

    private static void MakeFoo()
    {
        Leaker l = new Leaker();
    }
}

internal class Leaker
{
    private Timer t;
    public Leaker()
    {
        t = new Timer(callback);
        t.Change(1000, 0);
    }

    private void callback(object state)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Still alive!");
        t.Change(1000, 0);
    }
}
```

Much like [GlaDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLaDOS), the `Leaker` object will be indefinitely "still alive" - yet, there is no way to access the object (except internally, and how can the object know when it's not referenced anymore?)

Comment: There is still running code in this example, though.  The callback method will run every so often.  It's not a traditional memory leak until any code associated with it is also "dead".  You might be able to use something like this to create a traditional memory leak, but the example as shown doesn't yet qualify.

Answer (score 1):

Well .NET has a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) to clean things up when it sees fit.  This is what separates it from other unmanaged languages.

But .NET can have memory leaks.  [GDI leaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188782.aspx) are common among Windows Forms applications, for example.  One of the applications I've helped develop experiences this on a regular basis.  And when the employees in the office use multiple instances of it all day long it's not uncommon for them to hit the 10,000 GDI object limit inherent to Windows.

Comment: Were the GDI objects wrapped in .NET objects?

Comment: Yeah, the GDI objects are created from .NET directly.  For example, the Brush class creates a brush GDI object behind the scenes.  The garbage collector will normally clean this stuff up, but apparently we've found some circumstances where it won't.  Anyway, this is a .NET 1.1 app that's being replaced by a WPF app as we speak.  And WPF doesn't use GDI objects.  So that's one way to solve it.

Comment: The Brush object calls Dispose in its Finalize, so I suspect the leak would eventually be mopped up by the GC.  Still, even if it's not a proper leak, it's definitely an unwanted delay in releasing a resource, which is a *kind* of leak.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't referring to applications *using* .NET, which these answers discuss very well, but are actually referring to the runtime itself, then it technically can have memory leaks, but at this point the implementation of the garbage collector is probably nearly bug-free. I have heard of one case in which a bug was found where something in the runtime, or maybe just in the standard libraries, had a memory leak. But I don't remember what it was (something very obscure), and I don't think I would be able to find it again.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this is an important distinction that I didn't realize I was lumping together.

Answer (score 1):

One major source of C/C++ memory leaks that *effectively* doesn't exist in .Net is when to deallocate shared memory

The following is from a Brad Abrams led class on Designing .NET Class Libraries

"Well, the first point is, of course, there are no memory leaks, right?  No?  There are still memory leaks?  Well, there is a different kind of memory leak.  How about that?  So the kind of memory leak that we don’t have is, in the old world, you used to malloc some memory and then forget to do a free or add ref and forget to do a release, or whatever the pair is.  And in the new world, the garbage collector ultimately owns all the memory, and the garbage collector will free that stuff when there are no longer any references.  But there can still sort of be leaks, right?  What are the sort of leaks?  Well, if you keep a reference to that object alive, then the garbage collector can’t free that.  So lots of times, what happens is you think you’ve gotten rid of that whole graph of objects, but there’s still one guy holding on to it with a reference, and then you’re stuck.  The garbage collector can’t free that until you drop all your references to it.

The other one, I think, is a big issue.  No memory ownership issue.  If you go read the WIN32 API documentation, you’ll see, okay, I allocate this structure first and pass it in and then you populate it, and then I free it.  Or do I tell you the size and you allocate it and then I free it later or you know, there are all these debates going on about who owns that memory and where it’s supposed to be freed.  And many times, developers just give up on that and say, “Okay, whatever.  Well, it’ll be free when the application shuts down,” and that’s not such a good plan.

**In our world, the garbage collector owns all the managed memory, so there’s no memory ownership issue,** whether you created it and pass it to the application, the application creates and you start using it.  There’s no problem with any of that, because there’s no ambiguity.  The garbage collector owns it all.
"

[Full Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/resource-management)

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the difference between a cache and a memory leak is policy. If your cache has a bad policy (or worse, none) for removing objects, it is indistinguishable from a memory leak.

Comment: This reminds me of the title of a Raymond Chen post "A cache with a bad policy is another name for a memory leak"

Comment: Conrad: Indeed, that's the inspiration for my post here.

Answer (score 1):

This reference shows how leaks can happen in .Net using weak event patterns.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.NET can have memory leaks but it does a lot to help you avoid them.  All reference type objects are allocated from a managed heap which tracks what objects are currently being used (value types are usually allocated on the stack).  Whenever a new reference type object is created in .NET, it is allocated from this managed heap. The garbage collector is responsible for periodically running and freeing up any object that is no longer used (no longer being referenced by anything else in the application).

Jeffrey Richter's book [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) has a good chapter on how memory is managed in .NET.

Comment: This is not technically correct: some objects are allocated on the stack, not the heap.

Comment: Made correction to distinguish stack vs heap as pointed out by Steven Sudit.

Comment: It's *still* not technically correct.  Value types inside declared classes are allocated on the heap.  And the references to reference type objects can likewise be on the heap or stack, depending.

Comment: @Steven is right: The heap/stack is an implementation detail, with which one should not concern oneself when writing code in C#/.NET.  The only exception is when writing C++/CLI, which allows you to explicitly choose heap or stack semantics, the latter being a kind of poor-man's RAII.  In C# this does not apply, and you should never assume that a particular object will be allocated either on the heap or the stack, regardless of its type.

Comment: -1. Sorry, the only part of this answer that addresses the question of memory leaks is the fact that you mention the garbage collector. You've mentioned the stack and heap but nothing about the role they play in memory leaks or lack thereof.

Answer (score 0):

The best example I've found was actually from Java, but the same principle applies to C#.

We were reading in text files that consisted of many long lines (each line was a few MB in heap). From each file, we searched for a few key substrings and kept just the substrings. After processing a few hundred text files, we ran out of memory.

It turned out that string.substring(...) would keep a reference to the original long string... even though we kept only 1000 characters or so, those sub-strings would still use several MB of memory each. In effect, we kept the contents of every file in memory.

This is an example of a dangling reference that resulted in leaked memory. The substring method was trying to reuse objects, but ended up wasting memory.

Edit: Not sure if this specific problem plagues .NET. The idea was to illustrate an actual design/optimization performed in a garbage collected language that was, in most cases, smart and useful, but can result in a unwanted memory usage.

Comment: I don't believe this specific issue plagues the .NET String.Substring method.

Comment: @Steven Studit - The .Net Garbage collector uses something called a LargeObjectHeap, which is collected very differently from the other generations.  .Net doesn't doesn't like to throw "large objects" (only about 80K, iirc) away.  It's not exactly what he describes here, but it explains his symptoms.

Comment: @Steve, Joel: Not sure if the substring problem affects .NET, but it describes a "memory leak" in a garbage collected system that is caused by an unrealized optimization.

Comment: Right, I understand your post in terms of caching of references being a form of apparent memory leakage.  I've seen this under .NET in the excessive caching of the SMO classes.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you are using a managed dll but the dll contians unsafe code? I know this is spliting hairs, but if you dont have the source code, then from yourr point of view, you are only using managed code but you can still leak.