# How to identify memory leaks in c#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anatomy of a “Memory Leak”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104/anatomy-of-a-memory-leak)

Hi All
what are the best practices for identifying memory leak in c#?

Comment: How do you have memory leaks in a managed GC environment?

Comment: @David: by using unmanaged code, not cleaning up delegates/event handlers, storing object references in a factory-type object, etc. It's not necessarily as dire as a C++-style memory leak, but you can definitely still have them in .NET.

Comment: Related question: [Why can .NET not have memory leaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526037/why-can-net-not-have-memory-leaks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

[ANTS Memory Profiler™: Profile the memory usage of your .NET application](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm)

[ANTS Performance Profiler for optimizing your .NET code](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/be_ahead_of_the_game1.htm)

[Memory Leak Detection in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

First, install the latest version of the Microsoft Debugging Tools. Its a prerequisite.

To analyze memory consumption, I recommend you to download & use .Net Memory Profiler. It really simplifies all the process.

MemProfiler allows to analyze managed memory utilization from managed applications, windows services, asp.net apps and from memory dumps.

To find a leak on a process on a DEV machine, run MemProfiler and simply attach to the desired process. Once you are profiling, take a snapshots and MemProfiler will tell you which and how many instances are loaded, so you could know what is allocating your memory. Take at least 2 memory snapshots on different moments and compare them to see the “delta instances”. ( If delta is >0 then N new instances were created. Otherwise, delta<0, they were destroyed)

When to collect the memory dumps?

- You may take the first one after all the “required stuff” has been loaded, in example, after your app has responded successfully to a few requests.
- You probably will make a load test to the app before taking the second snapshot, because if the app has leakead A LOT, then its easier to find out where.
- You can also continue to load test the app and take a 3rd, 4th snapshots, just in case.

To collect a memory dump on web application on a production environment:

- You are not required to install the Debugging tools on the server. You can install it on a developer pc and then copy the folder to the production environment. E.g c:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)
- To identify the Asp.Net w3wp use this command (works with W7 and Server 2008, didnt tried with 2003) : `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp`
- To generate the dump, execute: `AdPlus -hang -p <process id> -o <outputDir>`

Other Tips:

- Generally your app will appear to leak strings, and in all the cases that I analyzed that was false. In my case, I used Asp.NET+WCF+IdentityModel, and they used a LOT of strings.
- If you are interested, do the “.NET Memory Profiler Tutorials” at http://memprofiler.com/tutorials/ and follow Tess Ferrandez blog http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/
- If you think that *probably* there is a memory leak somewhere, but you have no idea where could it be, [start by watching memory usage per process with Task Manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/alikl/archive/2009/02/15/identifying-memory-leak-with-process-explorer-and-windbg.aspx) or Process Explorer, looking for a process that eats always more and more RAM:
- Use AdPlus to generate the dump, avoid Task Manager, because Task Manager is a 32 bit process probably dumping a 64 bit one. MemProfiler gets confused in that case.
- When analyzing the objects in the memory, you will see an ExecutionEngineException, StackOverflowException and OutOfMemoryException on the heap. Don’t Panic. They doesn't mean that your application are raising that exceptions, [they are always pre-allocated just in case](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2009/08/10/why-do-i-see-executionengineexception-stackoverflowexception-and-outofmemoryexception-on-the-heap-when-debugging-net-applications.aspx):

Answer (score 2):

Use a memory profiler - attach it to the suspected process and run the suspected actions.

You can find some recommended profilers in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) question.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Profiling/Performance Tools allow you to track [Object Allocation and Lifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx).

Unfortunately, that's only available in the more costly editions of the VS hierarchy.