# Can there be memory leaks in .NET? If yes, what are the best tool out there?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I am working on a C# 4.0 managed code application. I am using external DLLs which are not CLS compliant.

Do I need a memory leak detection tool to check for memory leaks in the DLLs? If yes what are the best tools out there?

Comment: do you suspect a memory leak?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526037/why-can-net-not-have-memory-leaks/2526058#2526058

Comment: there is no "best tool" for this... it depends always on what the DLLs do - for example I have some DLLs which use unmanaged memory, other DLLs are native  etc. No tool handles all of these equally well...

Comment: No. But I have to check memory leaks every time as a part of our process. Thanks

Comment: Will the program need to be running for long periods of time with 100% uptime?  Should it have a rather large memory footprint?  Will it be running in an environment with low amounts of free memory?  I ask because in many cases it just doesn't matter if there is a memory leak as long as it's not really huge.

Comment: Also, asking for a "best" whatever here is not deemed constructive. At least give some parameters for judging "bestness".

Comment: It's typically not good to ask for a "best _____" since that's subjective, but I still think it's a good question from the standpoint of, "Can there be memory leaks in .NET"

Comment: Yup. Sry for that. I will keep that in mind

Comment: @Servy Yes we need. We have a multi threaded app which will integrate with other apps. So from our side we need high performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like CLR Profiler,VSTS Profiler, [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) or CLR Profiler to check your object size etc, as they say you can Find Memory Leaks and Optimize Memory Usage in any .NET Program.

Answer (score 2):

Even in managed code, you can have memory leaks. I would not dig into memory leaks unless you actually find one, though.

If you do need to look into a leak, then I would suggest [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), however this has its limits, so it should be taken on a case by case basis.

Comment: I was going to look to see if I could find a good reference about .Net code having memory leaks, however the link that Oded has, adresses this pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have memory leaks in .NET.  It is even possible to have them when you're using nothing but the base class library, because many of those classes themselves make calls into unmanaged code.

I once had a memory leak because I didn't dispose a System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection after enumerating over it.

However, I don't know what leak detection tools might be available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free WinDbg, SOS and GCRoot do diagnose memory leaks.  David Anson shows you how on [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx).  Rico Mariani also has a [good blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx) on using WinDbg and SOS.

Other products like [JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx), [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) can help you diagnose these kinds of issues.