# c#: does subscribing to an event imply reference to the object

Tags: c#

```
public class A
{
    public delegate void D();
    public event D E;

    ...
}

class B
{
   void Test()
   {
       A a = new A();
       a.E += () => { ... };

       a = null;
   }
}
```

Can `a` be garbage collected when `Test()` is over or because of event subscription there is still reference to it somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371109/garbage-collection-when-using-anonymous-delegates-for-event-handling

Comment: Closers - that's not a duplicate question. Very different scenarios.

Comment: Yes, it can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `a` can be GC'd in your example. It won't cause any problems either. Think about it.

```
Class1 a = new Class1();
Class2 b = new Class2();

a.SomeEvent += b.SomeMethod;
```

In this example, `a` holds a reference to `b`, but not the other way round. The `a.SomeEvent` member is like a `List<delegate>` (or close to it). It holds references to all the subscribers, so they can be called when needed.

So when `a` needs to be GC'd, it can be. It will be destroyed, along with the list of subscribers. `b` will remain happily alive without any problems.

The other way won't work though - `b` cannot be collected, because `a` is still holding a reference to it. If it were collected, then `a` would get a reference to somewhere nonexistant, and the next attempt to raise the event would explode.

Answer (score 2):

By subscribing to an event on an object, you are keeping a reference to the object.

You need to unsubscribe in order to release the reference.

In your case, once `Test` has finished executing, the reference that `a` was pointing to will be out of scope and be eligible to garbage collection - having the event subscribed to does not change that.

See my answer on [Why can .NET not have memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2526058/1583).

Comment: Don't you mean the other way round? The subscribee has a reference to the subscriber. But if the subscribee can be GC'd and the subscriber can't, it will get GC'd. In other words, in the example given by the OP, `a` can be garbage collected, no problems.

Comment: @Vilx- That's what I wrote. `a` is eligible to garbage collection means it will be garbage collected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confused by the first sentence: "By subscribing to an event on an object, you are keeping a reference to it." I understood it the other way round (b is subscribing to a and keeping a reference to it).

Comment: @Vilx- Fair enough, not the best sentence I ever wrote.